# Powershell Invoke-Command Remove-Item Remote Server

Tags: powershell

I want to delete files on a particular folder of a remote server. I execute the following in Powershell:

```
Invoke-Command -Computer 'compname1' -ScriptBlock {Remove-Item -$args -force } -ArgumentList 'c:\BizTalkDeployment'
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '-c' does not exist.
```

c:\BizTalkDeployment is the correct path on server compname1.

Can anyone please explain what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the - in front of $args and re-run the script.  You might even try changing the script block to:

```
Remove-Item -Path $args[0]
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, that's a great help.

Answer (score 3):

You could also remove the folder using a UNC path:

```
Remove-Item \\compname1\c$\BizTalkDeployment -force
```

Comment: If you want to delete files on multiple remote computers, [Ivan Versluis](http://www.networknet.nl/apps/wp/archives/943) has a nice little script.  `function delete-remotefile {
    PROCESS {
                $file = "\\$_\c$\install.exe"
                if (test-path $file)
                {
                echo "$_ install.exe exists"
                Remove-Item $file -force
                echo "$_ install.exe file deleted"
                }
            }
}

Get-Content  C:\Scripts\Active_Computers.txt | delete-remotefile`

Comment: Get-Content : Access to the path 'D:\install' is denied.