# How to move file on remote server to another location on the same remote server using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Currently, I run the following command to fetch the files to my local system.

```
Get-SCPFile 
  -ComputerName $server 
  -Credential $credential
  -RemoteFile ($origin + $target + ".csv") 
  -LocalFile ($destination + $target + ".csv")
```

It works as I'd like (although it sucks that I can't copy multiple files by regex and/or wildcard). However, after the operation has been carried out, I'd like to move the remote files to another directory on the remote server so instead of residing in `$origin` at `$server`, I want them to be placed in `$origin + "/done"` at the same server. Today, I have to use PuTTY for that but it would be so much more convenient to do that from PS.

Googling gave me a lot of material but I couldn't make it work. At the moment, I'm not sure if I'm specifying the path incorrectly somehow or if it's not possible to use the plain commands when working against an external, secured, Unix-server.

For copying files, I can't use `Copy-Item`, hence the function `Get-SCPFile`. I can imagine that remote moving, renaming and listing the items isn't possible neither for the same reason (whatever that reason is).

[This example](http://www.networknet.nl/apps/wp/archives/943) as well as [this one](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1788422-remote-delete-file-with-powershell) produce error *cannot find path* despite the value being used for copying the file successfully with the script at the top. I'm pretty sure it's a misleading error message (not being enitrely sure, though).

```
$file = "\\" + $server + "" + $origin  + "" + $target + ".csv"
# \\L234231.vds.afm.se/var/trans/ut/drish/sxx/meta001.csv
Remove-Item $file -force
```

Many answers (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11725910/1525840)) are very simple, which supports my theory that the combination of Unix and secure raise an extra challenge. Perhaps I'm wording the question insufficiently well.

There's also more advanced [examples](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/ask_the_experts/f/powershell_for_windows-12/9165/move-folders-and-its-sub-folders-from-one-server-to-another-server), still not working, just hanging up the window with no error messages. I feel my competence prevents me from estimating the degree of screwuppiness in this approach.

Comment: are you able to `Enter-PSSession`? In that case you could `Invoke-Command` to automate it...

Comment: @T-Me It seem that I can access the command `Enter-PSSession`. Not sure what to do with that. Could you elaborate on what to invoke precisely using `Invoke-Command`? I've never used any of those and feel a bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerShell you can create a PowerShell Session (PSSession) from your System remotly on another System (and into another Session on your System but thats details... ) and execute your commands there.

You can create a PSSession with `New-PSSession` but a lot of cmdlets have a`-ComputerName` parameter (or something similar) so that they can be executed remotley without creating a PSSession first.

A PSSession can be used with `Enter-PSSession` to get an interactive Session or with `Invoke-Command` to execute a ScriptBlock. That way you could test your `Remove-Item` command directly on the target server. Depending on the setup you might need to use Linux syntax within the remote session.

Here are some more infos [about_PSSessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pssessions?view=powershell-5.1) and using it [with SSH to connect to Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Just to confirm - opening a remote session works even versus Linux/Unix based systems, correct?

Comment: See the [general-setup-information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-5.1#general-setup-information) in the last link. You might need to enable something on the linux machine. However remote Sessions seems to be used in most of the examples you posted, too. (I would recommend to use Powershell 7 instead of Powershell 6 as the post states)

Comment: Oh, I just ran *$PSVersionTable.PSVersion* and I'm on version 5.1 at the moment. It's the employer's computer and I work for a government agency. Light and time slows down here, I guess.   :)

Comment: 5.1 is totaly fine It's nativ on win 10 PCs and has some features the newer versions don't have. 6 and 7 are based on .Net Core and are not bound to Windows systems anymore. Thats why they are better for interop with linux